# How do I reset Mathematica's DisplayFormulaNumbered cell style numbering?

Tags: formatting, cells, style

Since I am writing many equations, in various chapters, I need a way to reset numbering in this cell style. The following shows what I need:

x + y = 15                                   (1)

x - z = 12                                   (2)

*Next chapter*

3x + w = 1                                   (1)

This does not happen, instead of the last "(1)", a "(3)" appears.

Comment: A resembling type of formatting of the numeration I have used in the StyleSheet Textbook. There the numeration is given as (1.2) where 1 is the chapter number and 2 is that of the formula in this chapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I made the `DisplayFormulaNumbered` counter restart in each Section:

Step 1: copy the Default.nb stylesheet to a local stylesheet,  ResetNumbering.nb

Step 2: using a text editor, edit ResetNumbering.nb, find the section beginning `Cell[StyleData["Section"] ...]`, then move down to the command `CounterAssignments->{{...}}`.  Insert `{"DisplayFormulaNumbered", 0}` into the list, following the syntax.  Save.

Step 3: in the notebook where this is to be used, use menu Format -> StyleSheet -> Other to select ResetNumbering.nb as the stylesheet.

Vary this to taste.

This does not seem to work well retroactively, i.e. best do this before beginning the notebook.

Comment: I tried it and it worked! Thank you.